# Parse DateTime with abbreviated weekday name in Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime, parsing

I get a Date in the following format from an api:

```
   Mon Apr 29 14:40:17 2019
```

I try to parse it to a valid powershell Date with the following command:

```
  $test = [DateTime]::ParseExact("Mon Apr 29 14:40:03 2019", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",$null)
```

Powershell returns "Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

It seems that the problem occurs because of the abbreviated weekday format. If I remove "Mon" and "ddd" the parse works.

The information about the Format specifier is from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dddSpecifier

Anyone knows what causese the error?

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Windows PowerShell 4.0 or 5.1. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: As you are from Switzerland and your culture doesn't match the English abbreviations, replace `$Null` with `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture`

Comment: Adding the CulturInfo helped! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `$null` with `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` solved the problem.

The working code is:

```
    $test = [DateTime]::ParseExact("Mon Apr 29 14:40:03 2019", "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```